# Kohana 3.1 ORM: joins for has_many

Tags: kohana-3, kohana-orm

I have a users, messages and comments.

users id user_id

messages id user_id

comments id message_id

I can get users data of the message using with().

```
$model = ORM::factory('message');
$messages = $model
            ->with('user')
            ->find_all();
```

with('comment') doesn't work. I guess because it's created for one-to-one relations while I have message has_many comment.

How do I get comments data into $messages? Like the following: ['message_id']['comment_id'][DATA]?

Answer (score 1):

**0. Define relationships:**

User has_many Messages
Message has_many Comments
Message belongs_to User
Comment belongs_to Message

```
class Model_User extends ORM {
    protected $_has_many = array('messages' => array());
}

class Model_Message extends ORM {
    protected $_belongs_to = array('user' => array());
    protected $_has_many = array('comments' => array());
}

class Model_Comment extends ORM {
    protected $_belongs_to = array('message' => array());
}
```

**1. Get user messages:**

```
$messages = ORM::factory('user', $user_id)->messages->find_all();
foreach($messages as $message) {...}
```

**2. Get message owner:**

```
$user = ORM::factory('message', $message_id)->user; // without find_all()!
```

**3. Get message comments:**

```
$comments = ORM::factory('message', $message_id)->comments->find_all();
foreach($comments as $comment) {...}
```

Comment: biakaveron,thank you for you answer! I guess I wasn't clear enough. I have comments for the messages and want to get them in the same array as messages i.e. [message_id] => array([message_text]), array([comment]). In order to iterate them in one foreach instead of two.

Comment: You can do this with `join` but whats the reason? IMO, few small DB requests are more cacheable than one large. Add new message - and you must refresh whole cached data instead of just adding cache for a new message

Comment: @biakaveron  have a similar issue and for my (and I assume most) purposes the small DB requests that you get when iterating over the message objects and doing `$msg->comments->find_all()` are not cacheable because they carry the message ID, and there are thousands of them. Doing it this way is massively slower than a single `join` query and the resulting small queries are useless unless you want to blow all your RAM/disk on caching the entire data set - for something that MySQL does much better than Kohana.